# Triggers not working correctly

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger where the update customer portion is working correctly on updates.
I would like someone to help me correct the remained and show me what the format is for this code to work correctly for update/insert/delete triggers.

Basically what I need to do is audit the invoicelines and payments for insert/update/delete.
entries in auditlines must update the invoice table amount and customer balance.
Payments must update so that the due balance is adjusted.

I'm getting myself confused all over the place at the moment - probably because I havent slept in about 18+ hours due to this lot :(

Here is everything:

```
USE customercontrol;

CREATE TABLE customers (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  Address varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Username varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  Password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  Balance decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  INDEX Id (Id),
  UNIQUE INDEX Id_2 (Id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 12
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 8192
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE invoicelines (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  InvoiceId int(11) NOT NULL,
  Description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id, InvoiceId),
  INDEX FK_invoicelines_invoices_Id (InvoiceId)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 78
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 5461
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE invoicelines_audit (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  InvoiceId int(11) NOT NULL,
  Description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id, InvoiceId)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 452
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 3276
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE invoices (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CustomerId int(11) NOT NULL,
  Description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  Amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  INDEX FK_invoices_customers_Id (CustomerId),
  UNIQUE INDEX UK_invoices_Id (Id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 94
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 5461
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE operators (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  username varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  password varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE INDEX username (username)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE payments_audit (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CustomerId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  Method text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  UNIQUE INDEX Id (Id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2088
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 55
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

CREATE TABLE payments (
  Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  CustomerId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  DateCreated timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  Amount decimal(8, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
  Method text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_payments_customers_Id FOREIGN KEY (CustomerId)
  REFERENCES customers (Id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 60
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 16384
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER balancedelete
AFTER DELETE
ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET customers.Balance = (SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId)
  WHERE Id = Id;

  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance - (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments p
  WHERE p.CustomerId = p.CustomerId)
  WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount
    FROM payments
    WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      invoicelines.InvoiceId,
      invoicelines.Description,
      invoicelines.DateCreated,
      invoicelines.Amount
    FROM invoicelines
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER balanceinsert
AFTER INSERT
ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET customers.Balance = (SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId)
  WHERE Id = Id;

  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance - (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments p
  WHERE p.CustomerId = p.CustomerId)
  WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount
    FROM payments
    WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      invoicelines.InvoiceId,
      invoicelines.Description,
      invoicelines.DateCreated,
      invoicelines.Amount
    FROM invoicelines
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER balanceupdate
AFTER UPDATE
ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET customers.Balance = (SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId)
  WHERE Id = Id;

  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments p
  WHERE p.Id = NEW.Id)
  WHERE Id = NEW.ID;


  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      invoicelines.InvoiceId,
      invoicelines.Description,
      invoicelines.DateCreated,
      invoicelines.Amount
    FROM invoicelines
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER paymentdelete
AFTER DELETE
ON payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance =
  ((SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId) - (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments
  WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId))
  WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount, Method)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount,
      payments.Method
    FROM payments
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER paymentinsert
AFTER INSERT
ON payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance =
  ((SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId) - (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments
  WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId))
  WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount, Method)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount,
      payments.Method
    FROM payments
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

CREATE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER paymentupdate
AFTER UPDATE
ON payments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance =
  ((SELECT
    SUM(invoicelines.Amount)
  FROM invoicelines
  WHERE InvoiceId = InvoiceId) - (SELECT
    SUM(Amount)
  FROM payments
  WHERE CustomerId = CustomerId))
  WHERE Id = Id;

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount, Method)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount,
      payments.Method
    FROM payments
    WHERE Id = Id;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

CREATE OR REPLACE
DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
VIEW statements
AS
SELECT
  `customers`.`Id` AS `customer_Id`,
  `customers`.`Name` AS `Name`,
  `customers`.`Address` AS `Address`,
  `payments`.`Method` AS `Method`,
  `payments`.`Amount` AS `payment_amount`,
  `payments`.`DateCreated` AS `DateCreated`,
  `payments`.`CustomerId` AS `CustomerId`,
  `payments`.`Id` AS `Id`,
  `invoices`.`Amount` AS `Amount`,
  `invoices`.`Description` AS `Description`
FROM ((`invoices`
  JOIN `customers`
    ON ((`invoices`.`CustomerId` = `customers`.`Id`)))
  JOIN `payments`
    ON ((`payments`.`CustomerId` = `customers`.`Id`)));
```

Comment: You should edit your question and put there your table definitions for tables customers, invoices, payments and invoicelines. And in what table you want to create the triggers? Because you are doing a bunch of things in there.

Comment: You have a bunch of problems here. What do you want to insert in the audit_tables? The values before the update?

Comment: How do you connect payments with customer? you can have only one payment for each customer?

Comment: payment connects to the customer via customer id... multiple payments against the customers invoice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but i hope it will get you on your way:

When you want to update something inside a trigger, you have the NEW and OLD values that contain the record before and after the operation.
In the case of a DELETE on invoicelines, you have the NEW.invoiceID to connect to invoices. 
Then you have to find that invoice and update customer based on the customerID field. Then from that customerID you reach the Payments.

Here's some code:

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17661)</kbd>

(beware that in sqlfiddle the DELIMITER and DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' have to be stripped)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
TRIGGER balancedelete AFTER DELETE ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance - OLD.amount
  WHERE Id = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId);

  UPDATE payments
  SET amount = amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount
    FROM payments
    WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = OLD.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    VALUES(
      OLD.InvoiceId,
      OLD.Description,
      OLD.DateCreated,
      OLD.Amount);
END
$$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' TRIGGER balanceinsert
AFTER INSERT ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance + NEW.amount
  WHERE Id = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  UPDATE payments
  SET amount = amount + NEW.amount
  WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount
    FROM payments
    WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    VALUES(
      NEW.InvoiceId,
      NEW.Description,
      NEW.DateCreated,
      NEW.Amount);
END
$$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' TRIGGER balanceupdate
AFTER UPDATE ON invoicelines
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE invoices
  SET Amount = Amount + NEW.amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId;

  UPDATE customers
  SET Balance = Balance + NEW.amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE Id = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  UPDATE payments
  SET amount = amount + NEW.amount - OLD.amount
  WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO payments_audit (CustomerId, DateCreated, Amount)
    SELECT
      payments.CustomerId,
      payments.DateCreated,
      payments.Amount
    FROM payments
    WHERE customerID = (SELECT customerID FROM invoices WHERE id = NEW.InvoiceId);

  INSERT INTO invoicelines_audit (InvoiceId, Description, DateCreated, Amount)
    VALUES(
      NEW.InvoiceId,
      NEW.Description,
      NEW.DateCreated,
      NEW.Amount);
END
$$
```

For the trigger in Payments, You do the same rationale to update the tables you want.